# Краш кириллицы в хml

Tags: xml, кириллица, java, файлы

Я пробую скачивать xml, http://www.rusnovosti.ru/rss/culture.xml. Все отлично скачивается и пишется в файл. Вот код записи.

buffer = new byte[1024];
                    bufferLength = 0;

```
                Log.e("fileComp", "tryLoadFile");

                while ((bufferLength = downFileStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                    publishProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
                }
```

После этого мне нужно разобрать этот файл и я пробую его открыть.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(downFile);
    Log.e("fileComp", "all good, fis on");
    Log.e("fileComp", "fis = " + fis.read());
        int data = fis.read();
        String s = "";
        while (data!=-1){
           s += (char) data;
           data = fis.read();
           if (s.length() == 254){
               Log.e("fileComp", "string = "+ s);
               s = "";
           }
        }
```

Но получаю вот это:

```
<item>
<title>ÐÐ²ÑÐ¾Ð¿ÐµÐ¹ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ Â«ÐÑÐºÐ°ÑÂ» Ð·Ð° Ð»ÑÑÑÐ¸Ð¹ ÑÐ¸Ð»ÑÐ¼ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑÑÐ¸Ð»Ð° Â«ÐÐµÐ»Ð¸ÐºÐ°Ñ ÐºÑÐ°ÑÐ¾ÑÐ°Â»</title>
<link>http://rusnovosti.ru/news/294762/</link>
<guid>http://rusnovosti.r
```

12-09 02:44:11.297  32481-32501/com.example.s E/fileComp﹕ string = u/news/294762/</guid>
    <description>ÐÑÐ°Ð¼Ð° ÐÐ°Ð¾Ð»Ð¾ Ð¡Ð¾ÑÑÐµÐ½ÑÐ¸Ð½Ð¾ ÑÐ°ÐºÐ¶Ðµ Ð²Ð·ÑÐ»Ð° ÐµÑÑ 3 Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð·Ð°</description>
    <pubDate>Sat, 07 Dec 2013 23:13:00 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>

Как сделать читаемое отображение кириллицы?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/ -> читайте файл как UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(downFile);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
Reader in = new BufferReader(isr);
```

а дальше читать

```
int ch;
while((ch = in.read()) > -1){
   buffer.append((char)ch);
}
in.close();
```